# Programmatically generate list of combinations other lists

Tags: python, list, combinations, dynamically-generated

I want to create a list of possible combinations of a list of lists (example will explain better)

```
list=[[a,b],[c,d],[f]]
```

The result should be

```
acf
adf
bcf
bdf
```

The length of the list can vary, and the length of the lists within the variable list can also vary. How would I make this/these loop(s) programmatically? (preferably explained in Python or pseudo-language)

Comment: Don't call your list `list`. You're hiding the `list` type.

Comment: I know, this is just an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is for:

```
>>> lst = ['ab','cd','f']
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(*lst))
[('a', 'c', 'f'), ('a', 'd', 'f'), ('b', 'c', 'f'), ('b', 'd', 'f')]
```

Comment: Thanks! And it also works with [["a","b"],["c","d"],["f"]], which is great!

Comment: Yeah, that's the same in this context. I'm just too lazy to type all those quotes etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

list=[['a','b'],['c','d'],['f']]

for comb in itertools.product(*list):
  print ''.join(comb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursively:

```
def printCombos(arrays, combo):
  if len(arrays) == 0:
    print combo
  else:
    for i in arrays[0]:
      combo.append(i)
      printCombos(arrays[1:], combo)
      combo.pop()

l=[['a','b'],['c','d'],['f']]
printCombos(l, [])
```

Comment: what would be your "combo" variable then?

Comment: It is the combo seen so far. It starts out as an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

```
curlist = []

for firstobj in listoflists[0]:
    for secondobj in listoflists[1]:
        for lastobj in listoflists[2]:
            curlist.append(firstobj)
            curlist.append(secondobj)
            curlist.append(lastobj)
            print ','.join(curlist)
```